# How to Query **Current Data Storage Usage** from **Storage Usage**

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to know the way to retrieve **Record Type** in **Current Data Storage Usage**[image]

Answer (score 4):

This information is not exposed via an API (or a queryable SObject).

All that is available is the total limit value and the total currently used value (not broken out by object type) and to get that you need to make a web service call. An example of that web service call is listed in the idea [Access Storage Used information through API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006zM9AAI).

(If you really need the information per object type you could "screen scrape" the page you have included the screen shot of: annoying and fragile, particularly as Salesforce are moving the UI bit by bit over to Lightning so the page may change.)

Comment: Can u share any example related to Screen Scrape

Comment: @Rajesh I don't have one. In principle you scan through the page text you get from `String html = new PageReference('/pagePath').getContent().toString();` and match to elements and attributes that by inspection identify the data you want. If you choose to do this you should flag to your customer that it is a fragile approach. I _don't_ recommend you do this.